# remove parent node tag but keep children as is,xslt

Tags: xslt, parent

My input xml is like below, I want to delete  nodes `<multimap:Message1>` and

```
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
```

but want to keep children as is.

Since there is special character ":" in between multimpap and Message I am not able to delete this nodes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">`This one need to be removed`
    <multimap:Message1> `This one need to be removed`
        <EmployeeTime>
            <EmployeeTime>
                <externalCode>e82baef39</externalCode>
                <timeType>UK_MATERNITY</timeType>
                <userId>101046</userId>>
                <Holiday>
                    <date>2016-03-25</date>
                    <date>2015-04-06</date>
                    <date>2015-05-25</date>
                </Holiday>
            </EmployeeTime>
        </EmployeeTime>
    </multimap:Message1>`This one need to be removed`
</multimap:Messages>`This one need to be removed`
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor you can simply use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="*/*/*" copy-namespaces="no"/>
</xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/naZXpYb

With XSLT 1 you will need to run the `EmployeeTime` elements and its descendants through a transformation to strip the namespace that is in scope from the root element.